# Are there TypeScript-only comments that don't get written into the .js?

Tags: typescript

If I add a regular comment (either `/* */` or `//`) to a .ts file, it gets written to the output js file unless I specify `removeComments` during the compilation.

However, I wonder if it's possible to do it the other way round, keep comments except for "TypeScript-only" comments. This would be similar to how the Razor View Engine for ASP.net allows to use `@* Comment *@` to indicate comments.

I know I could use copyright comments (`/*!`) as regular comments and javascript comments as TypeScript only comments (and this remove them with removeComments), but that seems really awkward and hard to remember.

Without the use of additional build tools/processing, does the TypeScript compiler have a way that I've overlooked, or is `removeComments` the only applicable choice here?

Comment: You can remove comments in the compiler step: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html. "--removeComments"

Comment: @NathanielFlick Indeed, that kinda works but is awkward. Was hoping for the opposite (Keep comments except for the ones marked with a special tag). Oh well, can't have everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nobody finds an "official" way to do this, you could always put the comments in a section of code that you know will be [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript.  It's definitely a hack, but depending on your use case it could work for you:

```
interface TSOnlyComment {
  // this comment will definitely not appear in the JS
}
```

So that's a dummy empty interface named `TSOnlyComment`.  You can reuse that interface to make multiple comments, since TypeScript will interpret that as [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
interface TSOnlyComment {
  // This only appears in TS, not JS
}

const javaScriptAwesomenessFactor = 1e9; // JS rules!

interface TSOnlyComment {
  // Just kidding, TS is better than JS.
}

// let's print out how awesome JS is
console.log(javaScriptAwesomenessFactor);

interface TSOnlyComment {
  // Ha ha, we are laughing at JS behind its back.
}
```

That should emit JS something like (depending on your `--target`):

```
var javaScriptAwesomenessFactor = 1e9; // JS rules!
// let's print out how awesome JS is
console.log(javaScriptAwesomenessFactor);
```

So, maybe that works for you?  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, looks like no official way. Your suggestion is... interesting. It certainly works, though now I wonder if that's better or worse than changing the build process to somehow post-process the output ‍♂️